# How to execute an arbitrary command when open a new gnome profile terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to create a profile terminal that executes this command `rvm use 1.9.2` and leave me in the prompt after choosing my ruby version.

```
user@user-desktop:~/Sites/RailsApp$ rvm use 1.9.2  
Using /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

I've tried to put in "Run a custom command instead of my shell Custom command" [like I saw here](https://superuser.com/questions/342940/custom-command-in-terminal-with-a-variable) but this doesn't work:

```
bash -l -c "rvm use 1.9.2"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can put that command in `~/.bashrc` but it'll be invoked each time you open a new terminal(not for login terminals though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that command in `~/.bashrc` but it'll be invoked each time you open a new terminal (not for login terminals though).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a script, e.g. `/home/username/.gnome-terminal-rvm.sh`:

   ```
   rvm use 1.9.2
   exec "$SHELL"
   ```
2. Give it execute permissions
3. Set the script as the "Custom command" in the profile preferences